# Margin-top not behaving as expected

Tags: html, css

I created this quick [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cU7UV/) project to help you help me.

Why does `margin-top` for `#container` push the entire `body` downwards from `html` when I expect it to push `#container` from `#containerWrapper` ?

The idea is to have all the content inside container which would be placed with a margin right under the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by [margin-collapse](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins) which happens to two adjacent margins. The inner margin will collapse into the outer one and behaves like the one on the outer container block.

If you want to only apply margin on `#containerWrapper`, you could either use `padding-top` or put a `border` between `#containerWrapper` and its outer block container.

Comment: That works but adds a ghastly scroll bar (because the height is set to 100%), that article was extremely useful though, and I was able to get past this collapsing by rearranging my HTML a little. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For that Purpose ,You may use padding-top

Comment: @Ankit_Gautam that's better than nothing but, if I want to give it a different background then I'm kinda screwed. Do you know why it behaves like that ?

Comment: Then you chould use border-top:#000000 100px solid; in #containerwrapper

Comment: Thank's for helping me @Ankit_Gautam your remedies worked but it's a little too hackish for my liking, I ended up changing the structure of my HTML to fix the issue. Cheers.